# How can I catch the output of a redis query in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am learning nodejs/expressjs and redis and trying to catch the output of a simple query, whether an item is a member of a set of items.

Code example:

```
const isSet = client.sismember(key, value);
console.log(isSet);
```

I am expecting a true of false value for "isSet", and then I would use that in a conditional statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so what is wrong with your example?

Comment: For some reason the output doesn't get logged. It doesn't appear in the console when I try to "print" it.

Comment: you need to wait until sismember command executed. you need to add await keyword; await client.sismember(..

you can find further details in here https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Async/await has solved my problem, although at first I tried it like this:  Thanks!